# How to insert Splint into Makefile?

Tags: makefile, splint

I would like to configure my project in order to use Splint to analyse the different components.

How to add the command line into my Makefile, in a way it will ask if I want to run an analysis with Splint or just compile the program normally ?

Comment: Generally one doesn't get asked by make what you want to do. Generally you tell make what you want via targets on the command line (i.e. `make install` vs. `make` vs. `make clean`). Do you know the splint command you want/need to run?

Comment: @Etan thanks for your reply, not really but for now I just need to run the basic analysis command from within a Makefile...

Comment: What is "the basic analysis command"? That was my question. If you know the command (and what inputs it operates on) then you can just write a `split` or `lint` or whatever target in the makefile that runs that command.

Comment: I understand now ... I  was confusing a script that executes a makefile and the makefile itself ... because we use a shell script for our project which calls makefile according to some conditions....I will just add the command as you said to the makefile.

Comment: @EtanReisner could you please make your helpful advice as an official answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `splint` as part of the running of `make` you can either add it to an existing target in the makefile or you can add a new `splint`/`lint`/etc. target that runs the command you need to run.

```
lint:
        splint arg1 arg2
```

You will want to mark that target as a [`.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) so make does the right thing should a `lint` file ever exist.

You may also, for completeness/etc., list the files that splint operates on as prerequisites of the target. (e.g. `lint: $(SOURCE_FILES)` or whatever.)